# Would a redemption story be a coming of age plot

Tags: plot

I want to write a story about a man in a bad place in his life and how he finds his way back to his destiny. This seems to be to be a redemption story.

Looking at Monkeys with Typewriters, it seems to fit a coming of age plot. Do you think a redemption story is a coming of age plot?

Answer (score 1):

It could be both.

"Coming of Age" describes how a young person puts aside childish wants and needs and accepts adult responsibilities and priorities.

"Redemption" can happen at any age, and describes someone who has done bad things, recognizes that they are bad, and wants to make amends and become good (for some values of "bad" and "good").

I should point out that if your story is about a *man*, not a *boy*, you're going to have some trouble with the coming of *age* part, but beyond that, sure, you're fine. A story about a juvenile delinquent putting his bad past behind him to become a productive and contributing adult would totally work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Laura Ipsum on redemption but argue "Coming of Age" stories are more about losing childhood innocence after being exposed to the cruel realities of adult life.